# Web browsers working very slowly in Ubuntu 16.04 guest OS in VMware

Tags: vmware, performance

I use Ubuntu 16.04 in VMware which is installed in a Windows host OS. Firefox works very slowly, so I installed Chrome browser. I thought that the problem was gone, but Chrome works a little faster than Firefox and that is bad too, because on Windows Chrome works very fast. How can I get decent web browser performance in the Ubuntu 16.04 guest OS?

Comment: Most likely you simply have not given enough resources to the VM for certain applications to have decent speed. You may also be lacking guest additions and thus lack accelerated graphics and other hardware support. Really, this question is far too broad to give a useful answer.

Comment: I gave 2048MB to memory, and number of processors is 4. Does it not enough?

Comment: More RAM would help a whole lot. Try with 8192 MB.

Comment: **Voted to re-open** as the answer clearly provides a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

To improve web browser performance in the Ubuntu 16.04 guest OS allocate enough virtual hardware resources in the VMware settings for the Ubuntu 16.04 guest OS.

- 2 CPUs instead of 1 CPU
- at least 2GB of base memory
- at least 20GB virtual hard drive
- more graphics memory than the bare minimum amount

[image]

As a rule of thumb the base memory allocated to the guest OS should not exceed 50% of the available physical RAM. If you are running multiple guest OSs at the same time, the base memory allocated to all of the currently running guest OSs together should not exceed 50% of the available physical RAM. If you assign too much memory to the virtual machine, the machine may might not start.

If the host OS is also Ubuntu, install Open VMware Tools for virtual machines hosted on VMware. It is a suite of virtualization utilities and drivers to improve the functionality, user experience and administration of VMware virtual machines.

```
    sudo apt install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

Comment: If you want to re-open also leave a comment below the answer as that is what most people look at. (Done already, also **+1**)